# install statsmodels package in pycharm with python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, pip, statsmodels

I am new to Python and need to run a piece of code written in Python 2.7 using PyCharm. I have installed Python 2.7 successfully, and other packages and ran some code too. but I am facing issues while trying to install `statsmodels` package. I am getting multiple errors. the first one was about Microsoft Visual C++. I found a link on Stack Overflow to install it as it is no longer available on the official site. then, I tried to upgrade `pip` to the latest version but finally downgraded it to version 1.2.1 in between. Now, when I try to install `statsmodels`, I get the following error message:

```
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement statsmodels
No distributions at all found for statsmodels
```

Can anyone please help me on how to install `statsmodels` for Python version 2.7 and fix the issues I am having with `pip`? Thank you in advance.